# How can I execute a function with onclick in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, function, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am currently working on a NestJS-project, but I’m just a beginner.
My Web-application should display a leaflet-map with clickable tiles. For each tile I want to display a button which when clicked fires a function. Unfortunately, the  tags do not seem to work. How do I make the function work with onclick?
Is there maybe another option to write this?
Thank you so much in advance!

my code:

```
const onEachSurface = (surface, layer) => {
const textOnPopup =
  surface.properties.kachel + //here I display the number of the selected tile
  ' ' +
  `<button onclick = "addToCart()" class="bg-white
   hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold 
   py-2 px-4 border-gray-400 rounded shadow"
   >Add to cart</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addToCart() {
      console.log('hello my old friend');
    }
  </script>`;
layer.bindPopup(textOnPopup);};
```

on the front-end it looks like this:
[click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyQhV.png)

here you can see the error message from NextJs. The current funtionality is that one can click on a tile and the popup with the tile-number appears. The button should execute a simple function, but NextJs does not know the function. The number next to the button is represented by "surface.properties.kachel" in the code (a JSON-file is loaded in the background)

Comment: You're invoking the function immediately instead of passing it as a reference to `onclick`. Also, you should avoid inline JS as much as possible and use event listeners instead. `bindPopup` accepts a HTML element so you don't need to stringify the HTML: create your element using `document.createElement` and etc, which allows you to have access to the nodes where you want to bind your event listeners to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code to this:

```
const onEachSurface = (surface, layer) => {
const div = document.createElement('div');
const text = surface.properties.kachel;
const space = ' ';
const buttonAddToCart = document.createElement('button');
buttonAddToCart.innerHTML = 'add to cart';
buttonAddToCart.data = surface.properties.kachel;
buttonAddToCart.className =
  'bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border-gray-400 rounded shadow';
buttonAddToCart.onclick = function () {
  addToCart();
};
div.append(text);
div.append(space);
div.append(buttonAddToCart);

layer.bindPopup(div);};
```

Now it workes!
Thanks again Terry :)